# Is it possible to specialize a template for templated types?

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

For my program i need to define a *Solver* class which can either solve a problem or nested problem.

```
template< typename ProblemT >
struct Solver {
    static void a() {
        ProblemT::func();
    }
};

template< typename < typename SubT> ProblemT >
struct Solver<ProblemT< SubT> > {
    static void a() {
        ProblemT::func();
        SubT::func();
    }
};
```

Usage:

```
Solver<Problem1> solver;
Solver<Problem2<Problem3> > nested_solver;
```

In the specialized version of *Solver* i need to know both *ProblemT* and *SubT* types in order to define the types correctly and call the correct functions.

Is there just a simple error or is it impossible to define such a class?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `SubT::a();`?

Comment: It does not matter. SubT::func() just represents a static function which is called. The name of this function is insignificant for this sample code. The important point is to have the types of both problems: namely the main ProblemT and the SumT

Comment: You misunderstand. I meant to suggest that the specialization should be recursive and make use of the nested types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try something like this:

```
template <typename T>
struct Solver
{
    static void solve() { T::func(); }
};

template <template <typename> class Tmpl, typename U>
struct Solver<Tmpl<U>>
{
    static void solve() { Tmpl<U>::solve(); }
};
```

Obviously, you can decorate your primary `Solver` template with further member functions which you can access in the specialization, etc.

Answer (score 5):

You can do this using template template parameters:

```
template<template <typename> class ProblemT, typename SubT>
struct Solver<ProblemT<SubT>>
{
    ...
};

// And you use it like this
Solver<ProblemTemplate<SubProblem>> solver;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it does not exactly fit my needs. I have other generic algorithms which use the solver class.

I need to define something like
    Solver<Problem2<Problem3> > nested_solver;

Comment: @user1562958: You should state your requirements clearly in the question, rather than in comments to other answers, for example with the `Solver<Problem2<Problem3> > nested_solver;` the implementation has to be able to call `Problem2::f()` and `Problem3::f()`... or whatever your extra requirements are... (the explanation as of why you need that could also be helpful, I am not sure why `Problem2<Problem3>::f` should not be responsible for calling `Problem3::f`...)

Comment: @user1562958 I fixed my answer (per Luc Danton's comment). See if it fits your needs now.

Comment: @dribeas: I have a generic solver class which has to be able to solve normal problems and nested problems. Each problem itself defines own datatypes and functions. The nested problem has to be solved by the solver and not called by the main problem. So the solver has to be able to call 'Problem2::f()' and 'Problem3::f()'

Comment: @LucDanton: It paritally fits my needs. Thanks for your answer. But inside the 'Solver' i am unable to call 'Problem2::f()' without specifying a template paramter. Is this possible or am i misunderstanding something?

Comment: @user1562958 That's not possible, ever. The template is just a compile-time construct, you can't call a function on a template. So, yes, you have to pass a template parameter if you want to call a function. (Kerrek SB's answer might be what you need.)

Comment: Ok. Thanks to all for their suggestions and answers. I will refactor this part of the code.